# Ignoring No file or variants found for asset in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, github-actions

i am trying to run flutter test on pull requests and i have .env file inside lib directory which i git ignore but on the Github action when it tries to run the Jobs i get this error. Because inside the `pubspec.yaml` it's listed as an asset. [image: Github Action Result] i know why the error is coming but i don't know how to tell `pubspec.yaml` to ignore that file because it has no effect on the job it's executing.

Comment: So why you haven't posted `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a script that creates the file with the data and execute the bash script before running flutter test.

Comment: can you show how you have done it?

Answer (score 0):

use the `--no-test-assets` flag to avoid building assets bundle